# my php function strip_tags is not working according to my expectations

Tags: php

I am taking input as comments in my website. where i want few html tags to allow like

```
  <h2>, <h3>, so on. . .
```

and few to ban.

But i am also using a function which check the part of string and replace it with smilies 
let us say '<3' for heart and ':D' for lol

When i use function sanitizeHTML() which is following

```
public function sanitizeHTML($inputHTML, $allowed_tags = array('<h2>', '<h3>', '<p>', '<br>', '<b>', '<i>', '<a>', '<ul>', '<li>', '<blockquote>', '<span>', '<code>', '<img>')) {
    $_allowed_tags = implode('', $allowed_tags);
    $inputHTML = strip_tags($inputHTML, $_allowed_tags);
    return preg_replace('#<(.*?)>#ise', "'<' . $this->removeBadAttributes('\${1}1') . '>'", $inputHTML);
}

function removeBadAttributes($inputHTML) {
    $bad_attributes = 'onerror|onmousemove|onmouseout|onmouseover|' . 'onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup|javascript:';
    return stripslashes(preg_replace("#($bad_attributes)(\s*)(?==)#is", 'SANITIZED ', $inputHTML));
}
```

It remove bad attributes and allow only valid tags  but when string like <3 for heart come this function remove the part of string after <3 .

**Note :**

The smilies code which do not have html special chars < or > sign  work fine.

Comment: That's why strip_tags() is, for many aspects, considered flawed. A preg/str_replace() before passing to that function might help, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using PCRE to parse html, which is never a good idea.  The expression `<(.*?)>` will match everything from `<` up to the next `>`.  You need something more like `<[^>]+>`.  However, that still has problems (and will capture `<3`).  You could use a negative lookahead (`<(?!3)[^>]+>`) to handle that specific case, but there are a lot of other cases to consider.  You may want to consider using a DOM parser instead.

Comment: yes it works but i need a solution that work other smilies codes too. many smiley code use < or > sign. i want a solution that work with all